# Implementing empty iterators

Tags: c#, refactoring, iterator

I have this code:

```
    public IEnumerable<int> Iterator {
        get { if (false) yield return -1; }
    }
```

It is fairly ugly, but when you try to refactor it to:

```
    public IEnumerable<int> Iterator {
        get { return null; }
    }
```

The following code breaks:

```
foreach (var item in obj.Iterator) {
}
```

How would you go about cleaning this up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The .NET framework already has a method to do exactly this, by the way (making Jared's code redundant): [`System.Enumerable.Empty<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341042.aspx).

Comment: yerp this is my favorite by far

Comment: But ... its only available with .Net 3.5

Answer (score 10):

```
public IEnumerable<int> Iterator {
    get { yield break; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A better solution would be to define a reusable method for this problem.  I keep a method around in my shared library to take care of just this case.

```
public static class CollectionUtility { 
  public static IEnumerable<T> CreateEmptyEnumerable<T>() {
    yield break;
  }
}
```

Now in your method you could just call

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Iterator { 
  get { return CollectionUtility.CreateEmptyEnumerable<int>(); }
}
```

Comment: impressive.  Much better than `yield break;`.  Yes, I'm being sarcastic.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public IEnumerable<int> Iterator {
        get { yield break; }
    }
```